# Can I duplicate the Easy Digital Downloads plugin , give it another name and use it along with EDD as a different store?

Tags: wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

Can I duplicate the Easy Digital Downloads plugin (WordPress), give it another name and use it along with EDD as a different store?

My client wants to add 3 services separately, she does not want to use them as separate categories but want them as 3 different post types. So will duplicating the plugin work?

Thanks in advance,
Charles

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: Thank you. Have you ever tried that? Will there be any possible problems with payment gateway integration or settings?

Comment: i am not test this plugin but it is possible